# Excel edit web query import button is disabled

Tags: excel, excel-2016, excel-web-query

Hi am trying to edit the web query in excel. It is calling a sql procedure

It is allowing me to edit the query and when I click on the `GO` button I can see the changes(column headers) as well in the popup. But the problem is `import` button is disabled. So I was unable to see the data changes in excel.

[image]

any ideas why it disabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by updating the excel.

> Open Excel -> File -> Account -> Office Updates -> Update Options ->
>   Update now

After updating the version is

```
Version : 1707 
Build : 7766.2099
```